# Creating a branch in Git to add new feature to Android app

Tags: android, git, github

I am learning how to use Git for version control. One of the uses of creating branches is to add new features while `master` branch contains the stable code. I am using `Git Bash` for Windows in conjunction with Eclipse for editing the code.

So, assuming that I want to create a new feature called `social-share` and a branch named the same, how would I go about doing that?

Wont I first have to create a branch, commit the entire `master` branch to it and then add new feature code?

Comment: You know how to create a branch. Then what exactly do you want to know?

Comment: @RohitJain Well, won't I first have to commit the entire `master` branch to the new branch, then add code as needed so that I can create an apk?

Comment: No you don't have to. The new branch will automatically contain all the changes till the commit from where you created that branch. Did you go through any git tutorial about branching?

Comment: @RohitJain Just the very basic with some txt files and all. Nothing as complex as my requirement

Comment: @RohitJain Well, after creating the branch I should just clone it into Eclipse workspace. Any changes made will be to that branch only and compiling the project will create the apk based on the feature branch, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm assuming that you already have a branch called `develop` where your development occurs. 
The first thing to do is create the feature branch based on the current branch and switch to the created branch

```
$ git checkout -b social-share
```

Optionally if you want to push that branch to a remote Git repo to track it there:

```
$ git push -u origin social-share
```

Pushing the branch to the remote repo is dependent on your environment and whether or not you want others to work on this branch.

Once you've finished your changes to the `social-share` branch you'll want to merge those back into your `develop` branch.

1. First switch to `develop` branch

   ```
   $ git checkout develop
   ```
2. Merge `social-share` into `devleop`*****

   ```
   $ git merge --no-ff social-share
   ```
3. Delete social-share branch

   ```
   $ git branch -d social-share
   ```
4. Push changes to origin

   ```
   $ git push origin develop
   ```

***** The reason you use the `--no-ff` flag is so the merge uses a new commit object and to avoid just fast-forwarding the `develop` branch which preserves the fact that the `social-share` branch existed at one point.

If you want to read more about this branching model then checkout [the post](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) it was based on. Also, if you would like to learn more about git branching by actually doing it there's a great tutorial [series/sandbox](http://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/) that you should *checkout* (git it?).